# PassportJS with mongoose only sending half the data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local-mongoose

I currently have a mongoose database set up and have passport-local-mongoose accessing it working in hand with express-session so I can create a session cookie. The problem I have run into is that passport-local-mongoose will do all the hashing, salting, registering, and login itself. This is nice, but the thing is that in my console I can view the hash to the username and its salt, but the actual server can only access the username. The hash and other items by mongoose are never sent to the server, and I need to access them. I have concluded this is something to do with passport-local-mongoose as I can normally do custom hashing with things like bcrypt which work just fine.

For example my server will receive this,
{ _id: 5ffe64e9b6fe7b4ce115c9a1, username: 'myUsername', __v: 0 }
when it uses this code

```
MyUserModel.find({}, (err, user)=>{
    console.log(user);
});
```

However running `db.UserDatabase.find()` inside of my console I get.

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ffe64e9b6fe7b4ce115c9a1"), "username" : "myUser", "salt" : "SALT_HERE", "hash" : "HASH_HERE", "__v" : 0 }

I have already tried researching and looking here at stack overflow for this issue, and I have already made sure my databases are hooked up and connected properly. I can add and remove items to my database with my server, it just doesn't retrieve everything it should.

Why do I want to access the hash and salt you may ask? The reason is because I am wanting to explore some database encryption techniques which require access to these items.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find and return specific properties, please following this code

```
MyUserModel.find({}, '_id username', function(err, user) { 
   console.log(user);
})
```